# Repository Pattern on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I would like to use the `Repository Pattern` but I am stuck on the syntax. I want to get my function index().

First step, I create my folder `Repositories` and I create the file `AuteurRepository.php`

[image]

In my file **AuteurController** I have this:

```
public function index()
{
   $auteurs = Auteur::oldest()->paginate(5);
   return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'))
           ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
}
```

And in my **Model** I only have a file **Auteur**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'firstname'];
```

I have 2 questions:

1) In my file **AuteurRepository** how should I create my function **index()**?

I have tried this ?

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repositories; 
use App\Auteur; 

class AuteurRepository
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Auteur::oldest()->paginate(5);
    }
}


?>
```

My second question is in my **AuteurController** I don't understand what to do ?

I have this for now

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Auteur;
use App\Repositories\AuteurRepository; 

class AuteurController extends Controller
{


    protected $auteurs;

    public function __construct(AuteurRepository $auteurs)
    {
        $this->auteurs = $auteurs; 
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) In my file AuteurRepository how should I create my function
>   index()?

You can give it the name what you want, index(), allRecords(), ... . And perform the query you need.

> My second question is in my AuteurController I don't understand what
>   to do ?

If your repository looks like this:

```
class AuteurRepository
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Auteur::oldest()->paginate(5);
    }
}
```

In your controller you can access the repo index function like this:

```
class AuteurController extends Controller
{


    protected $auteurs;

    public function __construct(AuteurRepository $auteurs)
    {
        $this->auteurs = $auteurs; 
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $auteurs = $this->auteurs->index();

        return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'))
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Also, you can customize a bit the query. For example:

In the repository accept a parameter in the index method:

```
class AuteurRepository
{
    public function index($filters)
    {

        $pagination = $filters['pagination'];
        $order = $filters['order'];

        return Auteur::orderBy('created_at', $order)
                       ->paginate($pagination);
    }
}
```

And in the controller create the array to pass as parameter:

```
    $filters = [
        'pagination' => 5,
        'order' => 'asc',
    ];
```

or

```
    $filters = [
        'pagination' => 10,
        'order' => 'desc',
    ];
```

Or you can get the values from the request (be sure to leave a default value in case the request input is null)

```
    $filters = [
        'pagination' => $request->input('pagination')?: 5,
        'order' => $request->input('order')?: 'asc',
    ];
```

and then pass the parameter to the repo:

```
    $auteurs = $this->auteurs->index($filters);
```

Hope it helps ;-)